# Equal height on nested images in bootstrap 4 columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to dynamically create image grid like this:

[image]

What I get is this:

[image]

This is the structure I have:

```
<section class="categories-grid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row frontpage-images">

      <?php $categories = Roller::getBlock('Article/Category_Navi')->getTree() ?>

      <?php foreach($categories as $i=>$category): ?>
        <?php if($i == 0): ?>
          <div class="col-8">
            <a href="<?= $category['category_url'] ?>">
              <div class="image">
                <div class="caption"><?= $category['name'] ?></div> <!--  Category title -->
                <img src="<?= $category['picture_url'] ?>" class="img-responsive img-fluid"/>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div> <!--  col-8 end -->
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if($i == 1): ?>
          <div class="col-4">
            <a href="<?= $category['category_url'] ?>">
              <div class="image">
                  <div class="caption"><?= $category['name'] ?></div> <!--  Category title -->
                  <img src="<?= $category['picture_url'] ?>" class="img-responsive img-fluid"/>
              </div>
            </a>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if($i == 2): ?>
            <a href="<?= $category['category_url'] ?>" id="move-me-into-second">
              <div class="image" >
                <div class="caption"><?= $category['name'] ?></div> <!--  Category title -->
                <img src="<?= $category['picture_url'] ?>" class="img-responsive img-fluid"/>
              </div>
            </a>
            <script>
              $('#move-me-into-second').appendTo('.col-4');
            </script>
          </div> <!--  col-4 end -->
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if($i > 2): ?>
          <div class="col-6">
            <a href="<?= $category['category_url'] ?>">
              <div class="image">
                <div class="caption"><?= $category['name'] ?></div> <!--  Category title -->
                <img src="<?= $category['picture_url'] ?>" class="img-responsive img-fluid"/>                
              </div>
            </a>
          </div> <!--  col-6 end -->
        <?php endif ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And this is the css:

```
.frontpage-images img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Why can't I get the images inside `col-4` to be with equal heights and fit inside the `col-8` height? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: jquery and php are really useful here?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Since it is dynamic I need PHP or jQuery.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using CSS grid? `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid`

Comment: I meant for the question, it's a CSS issue, so I doubt that jquery or PHP tag are useful here

Comment: @TemaniAfif PHP is unnecessary  and I removed it. Since jquery is part of the grid real functionality I kept it inside tags.

Comment: @DanieleAlessandra There is no special reason but I just do not handle the css grid so well.

Comment: To do this dynamically I have used [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/), maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: I would think native CSS grid would accomplish this beautifully vs pulling in a third party library.  I am not as well versed in grid as I would like to be, otherwise I would post an answer.